# Who is Svayambhuva Manu's mother?

Tags: bhagavata-purana, brahma, manu-smriti, manu

Refer this [Prajapatis – the 10 sons of Lord Brahma](http://www.hindufaqs.com/prajapatis-the-10-sons-of-lord-brahma/)

It is said that Prajapatis are believed to be the fathers of the human race. Since all these sons were born out of his mind rather than body, they are called Manas Putras or mind-sons or spirits. So Brahma had ten mind sons and one daughter born from various parts of his body - Shatrupa. And Shatrupa's husband is Svayambhuva Manu who is also Brahma's mind son but none of the ten sons is named Svayambhuva Manu. So who is Svayambhuva Manu?

Answer (score 7):

There seems to be more than ten `Manasa Putra` of Lord Brahma as I have described in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19713/who-are-the-sanat-kumaras/19717#19717). Some `Puranas` include Svayambhuva Manu and Shatarupa also in the list of Lord Brahma's mind-born children.

According to Vishnu Purana and Shrimada Bhagavatam, Lord Brahma divided himself into two parts. Male part is Svayambhuva Manu and female part is Shatarupa.

> Then Brahmā created himself the Manu Svāyambhuva, born of, and identical with, his original self, for the protection of created beings; and the female portion of himself he constituted Śatarūpā, whom austerity purified from the sin (of forbidden nuptials), and whom the divine Manu Svāyambhuva took to wife. [Vishnu Purana, Book 1, Chapter 7](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/vishnu-purana-wilson/d/doc115942.html)

[Shrimada Bhagavatam, Chapter 3.12](http://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/3/12) also describes the same story.

> aho adbhutam etan me
>   vyāpṛtasyāpi nityadā
>   na hy edhante prajā nūnaṁ
>   daivam atra vighātakam (3.12.51)
>
> Brahmā thought to himself: Alas, it is wonderful that in spite of my being scattered all over, there is still insufficient population throughout the universe. There is no other cause for this misfortune but destiny.
>
> evaṁ yukta-kṛtas tasya
>   daivaṁ cāvekṣatas tadā
>   kasya rūpam abhūd dvedhā
>   yat kāyam abhicakṣate (3.12.52)
>
> While he was thus absorbed in contemplation and was observing the supernatural power, two other forms were generated from his body. They are still celebrated as the body of Brahmā.
>
> tābhyāṁ rūpa-vibhāgābhyāṁ
>   mithunaṁ samapadyata (3.12.53)
>
> The two newly separated bodies united together in a sexual relationship.
>
> yas tu tatra pumān so ’bhūn
>   manuḥ svāyambhuvaḥ svarāṭ
>   strī yāsīc chatarūpākhyā
>   mahiṣy asya mahātmanaḥ (3.12.54)
>
> Out of them, the one who had the male form became known as the Manu named Svāyambhuva, and the woman became known as Śatarūpā, the queen of the great soul Manu.

So, from above two sources it is clear that Svayambhuva Manu sprang from Lord Brahma's body.

Comment: The term SWAYAMBHUVA or SWAYAMBHU indicate self generated / created and accordingly the first Manu was the Manasa Putra of Lord Brahma (Creator) or created from the mind and not through 'Maithuna' or sexual relations between male and female. Hence Swambhu Manu has no mother and even his father Lord Brahma created him by his mental asectic powers.